# Thymeleaf mapping controller object implicitly

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I'm passing an object from a Spring controller to a Thymeleaf page which stores the object and resends it (possibly after a modification):

```
<form id="searchform" th:action="@{/myController}" method="post">
         <div th:object="${myobject}">
             <input type="text" th:field="*{field1}" hidden>
             <input type="text" th:field="*{field2}" hidden>
             <!-- al the fields here -->
         </div> 
</form>
```

I would avoid to explicitly enumerate all the fields. Is there any syntactic-sugar to do so?

Comment: Use @SessionAttributes on your controller... your model object will be persisted across the request and you won't have to bind everything.